# Parse cloud code: Can't change result set objects

Tags: parse-platform

I have an issue with setting an additional fields to the Parse query result set. An example code is below. Thanks in advance!

When I get the result set from a query in the server-side function I try to run the following code that doesn't work as expected.

```
querySubscribes.find(
{
success:function(subscribes)
{ 
for(var i = 0, len = subscribes.length; i < len;i++ ){
subscribes[i]['test'] = 1; // this doesn't work. seems like this object is kind of immutable!
}
response.success(subscribes);
},
error: function(err){
response.error(err);
}
});
```

Comment: Its a PFObject, `subscribes[i].set("test", 1);`

Comment: this doesn't work, if i use set method i get following error:

{"code":141,"error":"Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object."}

Comment: No, that means it is working, but there's another problem that the subscribes array haha one or more new objects. Those must be saved first.